# How to get google user profile on auth state changed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-signin

Im trying to get google user profile when i refresh my page i do:

```js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const storage = getStorage()
const analytics = getAnalytics(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)

const checkUserIsAuth = async () => {
 setIsCheckingAuth(true)

 await auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
   setloggedUser(user)
   setIsCheckingAuth(false)
  } else {
   setloggedUser(null)
   setIsCheckingAuth(false)
  }
 })
}

useEffect(() => checkUserIsAuth, [])
```

That user give me a `displayName` but i need `name` and `lastname`.

Split by `' '` is not an option.

i tried to get credentials when i use `onAuthStateChanged` but not working. Save credentials when i login is not safe to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google user profile is only available when the user actively signs in, so when you call `signInWith...`. It is **not** available in `onAuthStateChanged`, although some information from the provider may be available in the [provider data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#providerdata) of the user. If that is not enough for your use-case, you will either have to store the data yourself on sign-in (which you indicate not wanting to do) or ask the user for the same information again when you need it.